# Antlr4: not matched by right gammar

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have faced with very interesting problem. Let's look at it as an example.

**grammar1**:

```
TAG_SYMBOL: '@';
tagSymbol: TAG_SYMBOL;
```

**grammar2**:

```
TAG_SYMBOL: '@';
TAG: TAG_SYMBOL;
tagSymbol: TAG;
```

And let's parse "@" text with **tagSymbol** rule.

**grammar1:**

```
line 1:0 mismatched input '@' expecting '@'.
```

**grammar2:**

```
OK.
```

Why? :)

Answer (score 0):

When writing:

```
TAG_SYMBOL: '@';
TAG: TAG_SYMBOL;
```

the input `@` will always be tokenized as a `TAG_SYMBOL`, never as a `TAG` even though the parser might need a `TAG`. This is simply how ANTLR works. The lexer rule that matches the most will win and when 2 or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first will win.

The error you encountered:

> line 1:0 mismatched input '@' expecting '@'.

should be read as follows:

> line 1:0 mismatched input text '@' with type `TAG_SYMBOL`, expecting a '@' with type `TAG`.

If you want to have both a *tag* and a *tag symbol*, you should use parser rules for them:

```
parse     : tag | tagSymbol;
tag       : AT;
tagSymbol : AT;
AT        : '@';
```

### EDIT

The error messages can't be right. I think you didn't (re) generate a new parser and got confused.

Here are my test results:

#### grammar 1

```
grammar T;

TAG_SYMBOL: '@';
tagSymbol: TAG_SYMBOL;
```

#### grammar 2

```
grammar T;

TAG_SYMBOL: '@';
TAG: TAG_SYMBOL;
tagSymbol: TAG;
```

Test class:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("@"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.tagSymbol();
  }
}
```

Running the main class after generating a parser from grammar 1 produces no error/warning, and the parser generated from grammar 2 produces the following:

> line 1:0 mismatched input '@' expecting TAG

Tested with ANTLR 4.5.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for logic you described, grammar2 should be mistaked, but it's all right unlike grammar1.

Comment: But I have a "line 1:0 mismatched input '@' expecting '@'" error.

Comment: @NikitaKoval then you're using another version of ANTLR than I do. The problem remains the same as I explained: a `TAG` will never be created since `TAG_SYMBOL` is defined before it.